# How to edit the upload file field while updating the value in sonata admin bundle?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

while i upload the file from sonata admin bundle the file is uploaded but while i edit the file the file field also ask for the upload the new file.. please help me for the edit option for the file upload.

```
class Adds {
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\IntegerNode;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
const SERVER_PATH_TO_IMAGE_FOLDER = 'uploads/';
..........


       /**
        * @var string
        *
        * @ORM\Column(name="file", type="string", length=255)
        * @Assert\File(maxSize="5000000")
        */
       private $file;

      public function getFile() {
    return $this->file;
       }

       public function setFile($file) {
    $this->file = $file;
       }
    ,............
     public function upload() {
    if (null === $this->getFile()) {
       return;
    }
    $this->getFile()->move(
    self::SERVER_PATH_TO_IMAGE_FOLDER, $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName());
    $this->filename = $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName();
    $this->setFile(null);
       }

       /**
        * upload the file to the server
        */
       public function lifecycleFileUpload() {
    $this->upload();
       }

       /**
        * Updates the hash value to force the preUpdate and postUpdate events to fire
        */
    public function refreshUpdated($file) {
       if (null === $file->getFile()) {
       return;
    }
         $file->getFile()->move(
         self::SERVER_PATH_TO_IMAGE_FOLDER, date('YmdHis') .                            $file->getFile()->getClientOriginalName());
    $file->filename = $file->getFile()->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->filename = date('YmdHis') . $file->filename;
    $this->setFile($file->filename);
    }
    ?>
    And the adAdmin file is

     <?php 
    ...............
    ................
    class AddsAdmin extends Admin {

    ............
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {
             $formMapper->add('file', 'file', array('label' => 'File :', 'data_class' => null))
             ->end();
    }
    public function prePersist($ad) {
       $this->manageFileUpload($ad);
       if ($this->userLevel == Organization::LEVEL_CLIENT) {
       $user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
       $ad->setOrganization($user->getOrganization());
    }
    }

       public function preUpdate($ad) {
       $this->manageFileUpload($ad);
       }

       private function manageFileUpload($ad) {
        if ($ad->getFile()) {
        $ad->refreshUpdated($ad);
       }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the type of field;

SO for preUpdate/prePersist call your handle:

```
public function preUpdate($object)
{
    $this->handleUploads($object);
}

public function prePersist($object)
{
    $this->handleUploads($object);
}
```

and in handle just check:

```
       if ($file->getFile() instanceof UploadedFile && $file->getFile()->isValid()) {
            $targetFilename = md5(rand() . time()) . '.' . $file->getFile()->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $file->getFile()->move($uploadDirectory, $targetFilename);
            $file->setFile('uploads/' . $targetFilename);

        }
```